# Step by Step Installation of Nagios

Tags: nagios3

I'm a novice linux user and I'm looking for a step by step guide on how to install Nagios to  monitor our network usage (bandwidth and all).   I've tried installing it a couple of times, but it seems it conflicts with Koha 3.8, which I also have installed.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop edition, x86.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards